# How can I compile a .deb from Electrum?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, deb, python3

I am trying to make a .deb of Electrum 3.0.3 from the Electrum project at https://electrum.org/ which is in python 3. My goal is to be able to make a PPA so it can be more easily upgraded for a project I am trying to do as all the other PPA's are outdated. So I want to do this for the bitcoin electrum wallet amongst others.
I have been racking my head using stdeb among many other ways and guides to go about doing this. At first it was throwing errors about *.pyc files, eventually I deleted those and was able to make a .deb but it is making a dependency for python3-pysocks which there is no candidate for as python3-socks has taken over, and with that installed it still doesn't satisfy the dependencies.